# How to align buttons vertically exactly undereach other

Tags: html, css

I have some buttons "the ones with information icon, and I want to align them so that to be arranged under each other vertically

image_1 shown the current alignment of the buttons.

Please let me know how to achieve aligning them vertically under each other using CSS and HTML

I thought of setting an equal margin to the left side starting from the check-box but I do not know how to do it

HTML markup:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_SYNOPS_AGGREGATED_AREAS')">
    <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
</button>
                        
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_SYNOPS_AGRICULTURAÖ_AREAS')">
    <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
</button>                       
                            
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_SYNOPS_WATER_AREAS')">
    <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
</button>
```

**img_1**:

[image]

Comment: Just use a table.

Comment: Please include your ```html``` with ```checkbox``` and ```label``` + the css you have tried to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap classes such as `row` and `column`. So the layout would like this.

[Read more about Bootstrap Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

```html
<div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        Aggregated Areas
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <span style="border: 1px solid lightgreen">i</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        Aggregated Areas
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <span style="border: 1px solid lightgreen">i</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        Aggregated Areas
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <span style="border: 1px solid lightgreen">i</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the image I assume the box has a fixed width. You can use this as your limit and add an inline `span` between the text and the button and set it's width to fill the remaining available space. That should push the buttons to the right side.